# C# WPF Caliburn.micro handling opening and closing windows

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

1153/5000
I spent the last two days searching for a solution. Unfortunately, I found nothing, or at least nothing that would explain to me how to manage opening and closing windows.
I am new to programming, maybe that's the main problem.
But, my problem is:
I am doing a small WPF program using caliburn.micro and mwwm. The problem is opening and closing windows.
I would like to do a window management class or something like that, but I don't know how to aproach.

Could you explain to me step by step how to do it? I read the caliburn.micro documentation, but it doesn't explain how to do it.

In general, the situation looks like this:
I have a main window from which you can open several others. When i'm opening a  window, the main window disappears. After closing that window, the main menu appears again. I did it with:

'''App.Current.MainWindow.Show();'''

I would like to manage all windows. Opening them and closing. I came to the point that I should do it with Iwindowmanager ... but how? What? Where? I have no idea. Hence the request for a step-by-step explanation.

ps. Forgive me my English.

edit:

757/5000

There's a problem with that, I don't have much code because I don't know how to go about it. And wherever I was looking, I couldn't find a hint.
But of course I will show what I have:
To open one window from the main menu I have this:

```cs
IWindowManager manager = new WindowManager();
          public MenuView()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }

          private void ActionButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {
             manager.ShowDialog( new FirstViewModel(), null, null);
             this.Hide();
          }
```

To close this window I'm using

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
this.Close();
```

but if I use the first part of the code in a window other than the main menu, I don't know how to go back.

Comment: Caliburn.Micro has `WindowManager` class for showing windows. However, please share the code of your app. It helps others to understand your problem

Comment: I don't know how notification works here. I edited my original post. I added what you asked for :)